# Missing ThunkDispatch Types in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to install TypeScript and Redux Toolkit into an existing project. However, I am encountering a problem where `configureStore` is not providing a `ThunkDispatch` type thus I cannot use `createAsyncThunk` actions in `dispatch`.

To test this theory I created a brand new create-react-app project. Its `store.ts` file has the following:

```js
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

`AppDispatch` has the following type: `type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<any, undefined, AnyAction> & Dispatch<AnyAction>`

However, in my existing project when I have the following:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {},
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

The type for `AppDispatch` is just `type AppDispatch = Dispatch<AnyAction>`.

This project has many dependencies, but I do have the following:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
"react-redux": "^8.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.4",
```

I do not have `@types/react-redux` because the release notes for 8.0.0 seem to indicate this should no longer be necessary since the project is now in TypeScript. I have looked inside my `package-lock.json` and as far as I can tell there is no competing redux versions, so I am at a loss.

Why am I missing the ThunkDispatch type?

Comment: Not sure if you actually solved this, but do you have multiple copies of the `redux` library somehow in your `node_modules`? We've seen that break some of the store's types.  Another issue is if you have a file named something like `src/redux/index.ts`, and then try to import from `"redux"` - this can cause the TS compiler to be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your package.json explicitly declares redux be sure to update it to at least 4.0.0.